# Interpolation within window using spatstat leaves out one point

Tags: r, spatstat

I have a data frame of a mapped forest plot, where all tree stems have X, Y coordinates, diameter at breast height (in cm), and survival (0,1) (found here, named "MFP14_surv_forSO.csv": https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t10b53qcobvxlzg/AACZyASgudtFLiZ79QRIjHH_a?dl=0).

I created a spatial point pattern and then a smoothed kernel (im object) of large stem death as a proxy for canopy "gappiness" (or amount of light penetration). I consider large stems as those with a diameter >9cm, and a '0' survival indicates the stem died.

I'd like to interpolate this measure of "gappiness" onto all tree stems. I already know that there are several points in the pattern that lie outside the window, so I exclude those from the analysis using `inside.owin()` to subset the data frame.

```
surv14 <- read.csv("MFP14_surv_forSO.csv")
win14 <- owin(poly=list(x=c(0,250,250,225,225,0),y=c(0,0,50,50,100,100)))  #specifying window extent
surv14 <- surv14[inside.owin(surv14[,1],surv14[,2], win14)==TRUE,]  #removing points outside of window
death <- surv14[!is.na(surv14$diam90) & surv14$diam90>9,]  #subsetting only large stems
death <- death[death$surv==0,]  #subsetting only the large stems that died
death.pp <- as.ppp(death,win14)  #creating point pattern from large stem death
death.fun <- Smoothfun(death.pp,sigma=10,edge=TRUE)  #smoothed kernel of large stem death
im <- as.im(death.fun)  #converting smoothed kernel into im object
ext <- im[surv14[,1:2]]  #yields pixel values of gappiness for each stem
surv14 <- cbind(surv14,ext)  #adding gappiness measure to data frame
```

But when I interpolate, it is leaving out one of the points - there are 4873 observations in `surv14` and only 4872 in the interpolation, `ext`. So when I try to bind the measure of gappiness to my data frame using `cbind` I get the following error message:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 4873, 4872
```

I don't know how to figure out which point it's leaving out, and why. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this fails is a bit complicated.

I will try to go through your code and explain what's going on:

```
library(spatstat)
surv14 <- read.csv("MFP14_surv_forSO.csv")
win14 <- owin(poly=list(x=c(0,250,250,225,225,0),y=c(0,0,50,50,100,100)))  #specifying window extent
surv14 <- surv14[inside.owin(surv14[,1],surv14[,2], win14)==TRUE,]  #removing points outside of window
death <- surv14[!is.na(surv14$diam90) & surv14$diam90>9,]  #subsetting only large stems
death <- death[death$surv==0,]  #subsetting only the large stems that died
death.pp <- as.ppp(death,win14)  #creating point pattern from large stem death
```

At this point you have a marked point pattern with two different marks:
`diam90` and `surv`, and to avoid complications I will only keep
`diam90` (since we know `surv` is 0 for all the points):

```
marks(death.pp) <- marks(death.pp)$diam90
```

Continuing your code you next create `death.fun` which is an R function
of two arguments `x` and `y` and it returns the kernel smoothed tree
diameter at the location x,y which must be inside the polygonal window
`win14` defined above.

```
death.fun <- Smoothfun(death.pp, sigma=10, edge=TRUE)  #smoothed kernel of large stem death
```

Now you convert this function to a pixel image with default resolution
128x128 pixel over the enclosing rectangle.

```
im <- as.im(death.fun)  #converting smoothed kernel into im object
```

On a simple plot with the original window overlayed the digital
approximation looks fine:

```
plot(im, main = "")
plot(win14, add = TRUE, border = "green", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

However, you cannot perfectly represent the original window in this
resolution. Point number 1850 of `surv14` is inside the original window
but not the digital approximation:

```
inside.owin(surv14$X[1850], surv14$Y[1850], win14)
#> [1] TRUE
inside.owin(surv14$X[1850], surv14$Y[1850], Window(im))
#> [1] FALSE
```

Then you are subsetting a pixel image by a two-column `data.frame` which
is interpreted as a list of points and the pixel value for each point
**inside the window of the image** is returned. Hence only 4872 points
are returned:

```
ext <- im[surv14[,1:2]]  #yields pixel values of gappiness for each stem
length(ext)
#> [1] 4872
```

The simple fix for this is to use `death.fun` directly and skip the
pixel approximation:

```
ext <- death.fun(surv14$X, surv14$Y)
#> Warning in ppp(X$x, X$y, window = win, check = check): data contain
#> duplicated points
length(ext)
#> [1] 4873
```

Then your final line of code should work:

```
surv14 <- cbind(surv14,ext)  #adding gappiness measure to data frame
```

Please note that I have not considered whether it is a good idea to use
this measure of gapiness here. I will leave that to you.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed response! This makes a lot of sense. I avoided the pixel approximation and used `death.fun` directly, and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

AJ Brown asked:

> I don't know how to figure out which point it's leaving out, and why.

In the command `ext <- im[surv14[,1:2]]` you are using `[.im` to extract pixel image values at the locations with coordinates `surv14[,1:2]`. The help for `[.im` says that it has an argument `drop` that specifies whether locations that lie outside the pixellated window should be omitted (`drop=TRUE`) or should return an `NA` value (`drop=FALSE`). The default is `drop=TRUE` so that if you have any locations outside the pixellated window the resulting vector `ext` will be shorter than expected. So if you do

`ext <- im[surv14[,1:2], drop=FALSE]`

you can then use `is.na(ext)` to find the offending points.

You don't need the pixellation in this particular example, so it's better to just use the `Smoothfun`, as Ege advised.

Comment: Thanks for adding the note about the `drop=FALSE` argument; I should have checked the default settings more closely!